# Blank row appearing when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage containing two `<div>` blocks: `.fixed` and `.stretch`. Here you can see its HTML and CSS code: http://jsfiddle.net/p2bhuzs0/. My issue is, when I resize browser window so  width of `.stretch` block is less than its `min-width` value, a blank row appears above the block.

How do I make it not appearing, and, instead of it, make vertical scroll bar appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to effectively create a tabulated layout *(though not using a `table` as you dont have data), so why not use CSS tables?

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p2bhuzs0/1/)

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display:table;
}
.fixed, .stretch{
    display:table-cell;
}
.fixed {
    width: 420px;
}
.fixed div{
    background-color: limegreen;    
    margin-right:20px;
}

.stretch {
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    min-width: 300px; /* When less than this value, a blank row appear above .stretch block */
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

You'll then need to wrap the content of the fixed column in another `div`

Comment: Your fiddle made `.fixed` not actually fixed, but I simply added `display: table` to my `.container` CSS code, and now it seems OK, thanks.

Comment: @nomicos - indeed, I wanted to keep the class names to make it easier to follow- but glad you got your solution :)